# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-analytics

I updated my Android SDK last night (31.4) and after that I canot compile my app anymore.
I get this error:

```
[2015-05-01 14:36:24 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;
[2015-05-01 14:36:24 - SoFit] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;
```

I have not changed anything in my jars.
Here is my libs structure:
[image]

I tried to:
 - Clean project.
 - Restart eclipse.
 - Delete the bin folder.
 - Remove private libraries.

I also tried to remove the google analysts jar because I though that from the recent google play services update they put the analysts inside the lib.
But it wont compile either because of missing classes.

My guess that something with the google play services is wrong but I canot find what.

Answer (score 19):

Try to remove "libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar" from your directory libs and also update the code As v2 doesnt support anymore. Then Clean it and Run. Everything will be fine.

Comment: That worked like a charm! i missed that the first line in the dependencies in my gradle.build is:
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

Answer (score 6):

google analysts v2 is not supported anymore...
I have to use v4 which is included in the google services.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar` from your build and add Google Play Services.

The minimum required configuration:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer is WhiteHorse's: in my case the problem came about because I updated the Google Play Services Lib and it now provides the newest (v4) version of Analytics. However, removing the old jar wasn't enough as the v4 of Analytics it's not quite the same as the previous (v2 in my case). What I had to do is

1. Remove the libAnaliticsV2.jar from dependencies and libs/
2. Create a new EasyTracker class: check it out [here](https://gist.github.com/ameen-sarsour/8180ab52469191c4f202)
3. Quickly change the references to EasyTracker in my app